# jQuery Select One Element From Class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in a position where I need to use the `.slideToggle()` function in jQuery, on a regular JavaScript determined element.
I can use this code:

```
var feedback = document.getElementsByClassName('feedback');
```

and then a bit later on in a function:

```
feedback[index].style.display = 'block';
```

However, what I want to do is use the `slideToggle('fast')` function on `feedback[index]`, so instead of so brutally changing its `display` to `block`, I get a nice jQuery-esque transition.

Obviously this code won't work:

```
feedback[index].slideToggle('fast');
```

However this will:

```
$('.feedback').slideToggle('fast');
```

but I can't choose which feedback by index to run the `slideToggle()` function on, it just does them all, which makes sense.
If I could get some code that effectively does this:

```
$('.feedback')[index].slideToggle('fast');
```

That would be perfect. I like the fact that I can stick a class on something and iterate through the list of items that appear in `.getElementsByClassName('classname')`, so I don't have to stick an ID on everything of the same class, and it would be nice if I could choose which `$('.feedback')` element I am using in the list of all elements returned by this but I cannot figure out how that would work. If I can somehow choose by index which items in a list by class, to run jQuery commands on it would make this a lot simpler as I do not want to stick an ID on each and every item that has the class of `feedback`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : You can use **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to select element with specific index.

```
$('.feedback:eq('+index+')').slideToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery like this:

```
$(feedback[index]).slideToggle('fast');
```

Here you can see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CookieMichal/wcjusg2w/)

Comment: You'd need quotes and have to write it like this `$('.feedback['+i+']').slideToggle('slow');` and it doesn't work

Comment: Check the demo from my answer! :)